# Loop through js array in jquery php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to loop through a js object with ajax.  I was looking at json_decode but it didn't work because this is an array not an object.

```
var array = [{type: 'a', value: 1}, {type: 'b', value: 1}]
$.ajax{
  url: "php.php",
  data: {array: array}
}
```

My php code will be made to create a new row in a database for every item in the array.  How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean because there is no evidence of a loop in your code. Maybe go some more detail about the problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: on php side decode it using `json_decode($_REQUEST['array'])` and loop through it

Comment: SHow us your PHP code if it is that code that you want help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should stringify your array if you wont to send it as **json string**:

```
var array = [{type: 'a', value: 1}, {type: 'b', value: 1}]
$.ajax({
  url: "php.php",
  data: {array: JSON.stringify( array )}
});
```

after you can decode it with

```
$arr=json_decode($_REQUEST['array'], true);
forach($arr as $row)
{
  //do here whatever you want with your data:
  // $row["type"]
  // $row["value"]
}
```

but it is not necessary to send data as json. if you'll send it as array you can directly use it as array (without json_decode):

```
var array = [{type: 'a', value: 1}, {type: 'b', value: 1}]
$.ajax({
  url: "php.php",
  data: {array: array }
});
```

after you can iterate it

```
forach($_REQUEST['array'] as $row)
{
  //do here whatever you want with your data:
  // $row["type"]
  // $row["value"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two $.each loops and make a new array which will be passed in Ajax call

```
$nearray = array();
    $.each(array, function(key1, value1)
    { 
    //here key1 will be 0, 1, 2 ... and value1 will be internal array 

    $.each(value1, function(key2, value2)
    { 
     //alert(key2+' ->'+value2); 
     $newarray[key2] = value2;
    } 

$.ajax{ url: "php.php", data: {'array': newarray} }

    });
```